# Google Drive API insert permission only returns id

Tags: permissions, google-drive-api, acl

I'm using this request to grant user permission for a folder

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/{{id}}/permissions?sendNotificationEmails=true&fields=emailAddress,id,name,role,type,value
```

but it returns only the id field

`{ id: '0123456789876543210' }` like this

How can I get all other information in response ? or,
is there any BUG in Drive REST API ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation here https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/list:

The return resource is in the following form:

```
{
  "kind": "drive#permissionList",
  "etag": etag,
  "selfLink": string,
  "items": [
    permissions Resource
  ]
}
```

Which means you would need to specify your query field param as

```
items(emailAddress,id,name,role,type,value)
```

Rather than:

```
emailAddress,id,name,role,type,value
```

Alternatively, you can leave the fields param out to ensure you actually have the information available. Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks @Grant ! , actually my request as mention in the question works for sometimes and returns all those information. I'm using Postman to make requests. If I continuously do the same request it will return all details after some time period. I guess Google require a time period to create the permission we requested. Until then it only returns basic details like kind,selfLink,id... In this case I only requested the 'id' out of other basic information.

Comment: Please do try dropping the fields parameter entirely to see if that removes the delay. We run similar queries that do not have the issue you are describing.

Comment: I removed fields.Yeah, it works for just a single request, let say I'm making requests for several users by using foreach loop, permission granted only for one or two users. but weird thing is it returns Id,selfLink... for every user. :(

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean... it would be helpful to have: 1) The code that is making the requests 2) What you expect to be happening 3) What is actually happening. I will also say however that it is unlikely that you are experiencing incorrect behavior in the API. Please spend a bit of time with the docs I linked before and double check that your assumptions about the data being returned are correct. Good luck!